# Using a theorem to find the center of a $p$-sylow subgroup of simple group

Tags: finite-groups, simple-groups

I think that we can use the Theorem 5.3.3 of Carter's Simple book to find the $Z(P)$, where $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a Chevalley group over a finite field of characteristic $p$ as will be shown below. But I am not sure! May someone helps me?

> Theorem 5.3.3. Let $G=\mathbb{L}(K)$ be a Chevalley group, $U$ be the
>   subgroup of $G$ generated by the root subgroups $X_r$ with $r\in
> > \Phi^+$ and $h(r)\geq m$. Then:
>
> (i) U is nilpotent and  $$U=U_1\supset U_2\supset\cdots \supset
> > U_h\supset1$$ is a central series for $U$, where $h$ is the greatest
>   height of a root of $\mathbb{L}$.
>
> (ii) ....

Since the above series is central, $U_h=Z(U)$. So it is enough to find $A=\{r\in \Phi^+\}$ with $h(r)=h$ and then find $Z(U)=<X_r:r\in A>$.

Comment: Since the series is central, $U_h \leq Z(U)$, but it is not equal in the case of $B_n$, $C_n$, $F_4$ when the characteristic is 2, or $G_2$ when the characteristic is 3.

Comment: This is basically what I did though. The general answer is exactly $U_h$ in the untwisted case (so general, as in, not char 2 or 3). In the twisted case, I think it is $Z(U_h)$ where $U_h = \langle X_r : r \in A \rangle$ (except in exceptional characteristics, but I think there are not actually any exceptions for the twisted groups, all chars work the same).

Comment: If we show that $U_{h-1}$ contains an element which is not in $Z(U)$ then is it enough to show $Z(U)=U_h$?

Comment: I think, it is not enough!

Comment: Not in general enough. A (nilpotent) group can have many central series. The smallest non-identity terms are all contained in the center, but the second-to-smallest non-identity terms can seem pretty unrelated to the center (they are contained in the second center, but within the second center they can be any subgroup).